# error C2665: 'cv::fillPoly' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I get this strange error, where this code compiles (and displays a triangle correctly):

```
Point pts[3] = { Point(20, 20), Point(60, 20), Point(40, 40) };
const Point *ptsp = pts;
int npts[1] = {3};  
fillPoly(img, &ptsp, npts, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 0));
```

But if I replace `const Point *ptsp = pts;` with `Point *ptsp = pts`, then I get this error:

```
1>C:\Workspace\ImageProcessing\Tutorials\src\main.cpp(16): error C2665: 'cv::fillPoly' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          C:\Workspace\ImageProcessing\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/core.hpp(2632): could be 'void cv::fillPoly(cv::Mat &,const cv::Point **,const int *,int,const cv::Scalar &,int,int,cv::Point)'
1>          C:\Workspace\ImageProcessing\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/core.hpp(2637): or       'void cv::fillPoly(cv::InputOutputArray,cv::InputArrayOfArrays,const cv::Scalar &,int,int,cv::Point)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(cv::Mat, cv::Point **, int [1], int, cv::Scalar_<_Tp>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Tp=double
1>          ]
```

But normally you should be able to pass non-const pointers where the function expects a const pointer, so why does it fail to work here?

I had used `Point *ptsp = pts;` at first, of course, and it took me quite some time and head-scratching to figure out it needs to be `const`, and it was totally unexpected for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained here : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html

> The reason the conversion from Foo** → Foo const** is dangerous is that it would let you silently and accidentally modify a const Foo object without a cast:
>       class Foo {
>       public:
>         void modify();  // make some modification to the this object
>       };
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>   const Foo x;
>   Foo* p;
>   Foo const** q = &p;  // q now points to p; this is (fortunately!) an error
>   *q = &x;             // p now points to x
>   p->modify();         // Ouch: modifies a const Foo!!
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> If the q = &p line were legal, q would be pointing at p. The next line, *q = &x, changes p itself (since *q is p) to point at x. That would be a bad thing, since we would have lost the const qualifier: p is a Foo* but x is a const Foo. The p->modify() line exploits p's ability to modify its referent, which is the real problem, since we ended up modifying a const Foo.